# Can you explain how to migrate / generate an html code to another html code - PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code this PHP code generates 5 `li` tags

```
<?php
function calculate_stars($max, $rating){
    $full_stars=floor($rating);
    $half_stars = ceil($rating-$full_stars);
    $gray_stars = $max-($full_stars + $half_stars);
    return array ($full_stars, $half_stars, $gray_stars);
}

function display_star($rating){
    $output="";
    $number_stars = calculate_stars(5,$rating);
    $full = $number_stars[0];
    $half = $number_stars[1];
    $gray = $number_stars[2];
    $output ='<ul class="star-rating">';
    if($gray)
        for ($i=0;$i<$gray;$i++)
        {
            $output .= '<li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>';
        }

    if($half){
        $output .= '<li class="star-icon half">&#9734;</li>';
    }

    if($full){
        for($i=0; $i<$full;$i++)
        {
            $output .= '<li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>';
        }
    }

    $output .='</ul>';
    return $output;

}

echo display_star(0.3);

exit;
?>
```

Result:

```
<ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon half">&#9734;</li>
</ul>
```

> Explanation about `$half` and `$full`

The variable `$half` add class `class="star-icon half"` result:

[image]

The variable `$full` add class `class="star-icon full"` result:

[image]

The half star is equivalent to: `0.5` `1.5` `2.5` `3.5` `4.5`

The full star is equivalent to: `1` `2` `3` `4` `5`

And all this is controlled by means of:

```
echo display_star(0.5);
```

> You can do tests [here](https://ideone.com/JZFsg6) in the php code and the generated html code you can paste [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mvesg09e/) to see the results.

---

***Now my question***

**How can I generate 10 `li` tags in the following order respecting their data and classes according to the value of php `display_star(4.5);` ?**

In the new code to generate must have in all `li` class `class="c-rating__item"` and the class `left` exchanging one (or passing a `li` ) and the `data-index` in the order as it is, in this way must generate me the html code by means of this value of php `display_star(0.5);`.

```
<ul class="c-rating">
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="1"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="2"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="3"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="4"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="5"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="6"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

The stars in the middle are equivalent to the following data-index `0` `2` `4` `6` `8`

And the `is-active` class is the global manager of filling in all the stars or half of the star.

Practical example if we generate a html code of a rating `display_star(3.5);` the result should be the following:

```
<ul class="c-rating">
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="0"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="2"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="4"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="5"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item is-active left" data-index="6"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="7"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item left" data-index="8"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item" data-index="9"></li>
</ul>
```

> **Note:** The css styles of the class [here show two examples full stars and middle star](https://jsfiddle.net/0nbhmqgb/1/) to get to understand more thoroughly.

Comment: can you explain what is $half and $full ?

Comment: @AmLy add style of classes through php by means of values, it is interesting to think that this could only be done using jquery

Comment: @AmLy updated my answer... hope it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
function calculate_stars($rating){
    // step starting from 0
    return (($rating/0.5)-1);
}

function display_star($rating){
    $output="";
    $step = calculate_stars($rating);
    $output ='<ul class="c-rating">';
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        $class = '';
        if($i<=$step)  $class = ' is-active';
        if($i%2 == 0) $class .= ' left';
        $output .= '<li class="c-rating__item'. $class.'" data-index="'.$i.'"></li>';
    }

    $output .='</ul>';
    return $output;

}

echo display_star(3.5);

exit;
```

Explanation: Consider a step scale of 10 start from 0. each step is 0.5

As per your question

- if rating is 1 `li` 's index 0 and 1 should have `is-active` class - means up to step scale = 1 assign `is-active`
- If rating is 1.5 `li`'s index 0,1 and 2 should have `is-active` class - means up to step scale = 2 assign `is-active`
- If rating is 3.5 `li`'s index 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 should have `is-active` class - means up to step scale = 6 assign `is-active`

Comment: I forget a single detail should add the class `rating` in the last class `is-active`

Comment: add if($i==$step)  $class = ' rating'; next to if($i<=$step)  $class = ' is-active';

Comment: To culminate friend you can update the question with the request. And it will be possible to explain how the php code works to fully understand its operation thanks :)

Comment: sure but I don't know how to lead this comments section into chat

Comment: I have no idea friend how to put this in the chat, try to post several comments but does not show link transfer to chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_star($rating){
    $output="";
    $max = 10;

    if($rating > 5){return;}

    $num = $rating *2;
    $num_half = ceil($rating) * 2;
    echo $num_half . '<br>';

    $output ='<ul class="c-rating">';

        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
            $class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? "is-active left" : "is-active";
            $output .=  '<li class="c-rating__item ' . $class . '" data-index=' . $i . ' >c-rating__item ' . $class . '</li>';
        }

        $class = ($class != "is-active left") ? "left" : "";

        for($i=$num;$i<$max;$i++){
            $output .=  '<li class="c-rating__item ' . $class . '" data-index=' . $i . ' >c-rating__item ' . $class . '</li>';
            $class = ($class != "left") ? "left" : "";
        }

    $output .='</ul>';

    return $output;

}


echo display_star(2.5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
$number_stars = calculate_stars(5,$rating);
```

To:

```
$number_stars = calculate_stars(10,$rating);
```

Comment: What about `c-rating__item` and `left` classes? What about `data-index` attribute?