# Can you explain how the formulas implemented in the two functions work?

Tags: php, function

The two functions are based on a product classification system, based on votes from 0.5 to 5 points, that is: (0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5).

But how mathematical or arithmetic calculations work?

```
function calculate_stars($rating){
    // step starting from 0
    return (($rating/0.5)-1);
}
```

And this what tells us this, how it works:

```
function display_star($rating){
    $output="";
    $step = calculate_stars($rating);
    $output ='<ul class="c-rating">';
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        $class = '';
        if($i<=$step)  $class = ' is-active';
        if($i%2 == 0) $class .= ' left';
        $output .= '<li class="c-rating__item'. $class.'" data-index="'.$i.'"></li>';
    }

    $output .='</ul>';
    return $output;

}

echo display_star(0.5);
```

[image]

Can you explain, each arithmetic or mathematical process to understand and learn how these functions work correctly?

Comment: For some reason it turns 4.5 into 8 "steps" and then prints html to represent half stars. It does this by checking if each step is divisbile by 2.

Comment: 4.5 / 0.5 in calculate_stars() equals 9 minus 1 is a final result of 8 -- that's mathematically correct.

Comment: It's also going to turn 0.5 stars into 0 steps and 0 stars into -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I devised the following in an attempt to better grasp the code:

```
<?php
const OFFSET = 0.5;
function calculate_stars($rating){
    return ( ($rating/OFFSET) - 1 );
}
function display_star($rating){
    $output="";
    $str = "";
    $step = calculate_stars($rating);

    for ($i=0, $max = 10; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        echo str_pad($output,$i,"*"),"\n";
    }
}

display_star(0.5);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/E13gL)

Then, I discovered a related link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652807/can-you-explain-how-to-migrate-generate-an-html-code-to-another-html-code-ph) and found the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653288/701302) that seems to form the basis of OP's questions. Therefore, the following remarks pertain to the OP's example code.

The function display_star() gets the ball rolling so-to-speak by taking a rating parameter.  That function calls calculate_stars() with an initial $rating of 0.5. The callback returns a value that sets $step. The for-loop  generates a row of 5 stars, each star composed of two-halves which makes it convenient to represent a rating of 0.5 with a half filled in star.

The function calculate_stars() takes a parameter $rating and returns a value that sets `$step`.  To determine how many half and/or full stars to output, the function uses an algorithm such that it divides the rating by 0.5 or a half, fitting for the one-half incremented values in a 0.5 to 5.0 star rating system.  Next, one is subtracted from that result, so that the final result determines how many stars are fully or partially active, i.e. a rating of 0.5 translates into step 0, so there will be exactly only one half star while the remaining four stars are blank.

In display_star(), the first if-conditional tests that `$i` is less than or equivalent to the step value. If that statement evaluates as true then the variable `$class` is assigned a class of "is_active".  The next if-statement uses a modulo operation so that in every other iteration of the for-loop the value of `$class` expands to include another class, namely "left".  The PHP code generates HTML consisting of ten **li** elements which the accompanying CSS transforms into a half star followed by four blank stars; see the calculated result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vp3r2rLL/4/).

Comment: Nice, you don't have to exit out if you want to redefine a function or object.  I'll have to remember that.

Comment: @slevy1 Thanks friend for answering, apologize you can add more information I have to explain it to the teacher and there are still things that I do not understand, I understand clearly that the second function creates 10 li starting from 0 to 9.

Comment: @slevy1 But you can explain to me more in depth that it controls this: `return (($rating/0.5)-1);`, taking an example of a supesision of a rating of 1 star or of 5 according to your taste.

Comment: @slevy1 As I mentioned earlier, I know that the for loop (`for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)`) creates a data number starting from 0 to 9. 
but within that for loop, I do not understand the two `if` what verification does, and what does `if($i<=$step)` and this other that checks `if($i%2 == 0)` please explain me taking example of a star rating either from a rating of 1 or 5 in order to be able to understand what it does.

Comment: @OneL I've included an explanation in my revised answer.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use interactive mode to see what it does:

```
php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > function calculate_stars($rating){
php {     // step starting from 0
php {     return (($rating/0.5)-1);
php { }
php > 
php > function display_star($rating){
php {     //$output="";
php {     $out = array();
php {     $step = calculate_stars($rating);
php {     //$output ='<ul class="c-rating">';
php {     for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
php {     {
php {         $class = '';
php {         if($i<=$step)  $class = ' is-active';
php {         if($i%2 == 0) $class .= ' left';
php {         //$output .= '<li class="c-rating__item'. $class.'" data-index="'.$i.'"></li>';
php {         $out[] = str_pad($class, 14, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
php {     }
php { 
php {     //$output .='</ul>';
php {     //return $output;
php {     return implode($out,' | ');
php { 
php { }
php > 
php > for($i=0.5; $i <= 5; $i+=0.5) {
php {   printf("% 3s: %d %s\n",
php (     $i,
php (     calculate_stars($i),
php (     display_star($i)
php (   );
php { }
0.5: 0  is-active left |                |           left |                |           left |                |           left |                |           left |               
  1: 1  is-active left |      is-active |           left |                |           left |                |           left |                |           left |               
1.5: 2  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |                |           left |                |           left |                |           left |               
  2: 3  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |           left |                |           left |                |           left |               
2.5: 4  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |                |           left |                |           left |               
  3: 5  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |           left |                |           left |               
3.5: 6  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |                |           left |               
  4: 7  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |           left |               
4.5: 8  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |               
  5: 9  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active |  is-active left |      is-active
php >
```

You have 10 possible ratings, in .5 increments.  So `display_star($rating)` steps through all 10, giving the appropriate class.  The star that is displayed depends on the class given.  So for each set of stars, there are 10 `<li>` with varying classes.  Check your CSS to see what each one of them does.

Comment: Thanks friend for answering, apologize you can add more information I have to explain it to the teacher and there are still things that I do not understand, I understand clearly that the second function creates 10 li starting from 0 to 9.

Comment: But you can explain to me more in depth that it controls this: `return (($rating/0.5)-1);`, taking an example of a supesision of a rating of 1 star or of 5 according to your taste.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I know that the for loop (`for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)`) creates a data number starting from 0 to 9. but within that for loop, I do not understand the two `if` what verification does, and what does `if($i<=$step)` and this other that checks `if($i%2 == 0)` please explain me taking example of a star rating either from a rating of 1 or 5 in order to be able to understand what it does.